# How to set up a task that does something to APKs built by Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I need to set up a custom task that I run after an APK is built when using Gradle for Android. Right now I actually have two tasks. One builds an XML file using the path to the APK as an input, and the other runs after the XML task (named `packageConfig`) and bundles the APK and the XML file into a ZIP.

Right now, I'm having trouble with my `packageConfig` task. It runs the python script for only the "fullRelease" product flavor, when I actually have multiple:

- x86Debug
- x86Release
- armDebug
- armRelease
- fullDebug
- fullRelease

My script is only executed once, and for the wrong APK. For example, I will invoke gradle like so:

```
$ gradlew :Applications:zApp:assemblex86debug packageConfig
```

I set up a `print()` call in my python script to output the APK path passed in, and it is:

```
build\outputs\apk\full\release\zApp.apk
```

The path I'm expecting (based on the product flavor I chose on the command line, as well as the APK I know that is there):

```
build\outputs\apk\x86\debug\zApp.apk
```

I'll paste my gradle task below. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? What corrections can I make to my script to get it to run my script on the correct APK?

```
task packageConfig(type: Exec) {
    def buildCommit = getBuildCommit()
    def buildBranch = getVcsBranchName()
    def buildDescription = buildBranch + '-' + buildCommit
    def buildDate = getBuildDate()

    workingDir buildscript.sourceFile.parent
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def apk = output.outputFile
            def apkDir = apk.getParent();
            def inputConfig = '' + project.projectDir + File.separator +
                packageConfigXmlFile
            def outputConfig = apkDir + File.separator + 'PackageConfig.xml'

            commandLine 'python', 'setup-package-config.py', versions.version, inputConfig,
                outputConfig, apk, buildDescription
        }
    }
}
```